# Checking list of objects for differences

Tags: c#

I have the following two lists:

```
List<MyObject> oldList = new List<MyObject>();
oldList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 1, Name = "hello" });
oldList.Add(New MyObject { Id = 2, Name = "world" });

List<MyObject> newList = new List<MyObject>();
newList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 1, Name = "Hello" });
newList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 3, Name = "World" });
newList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 4, Name = "hello" });
```

I would like to write something to compare the two lists and return boolean true if the lists are different.

For example, the lists above are different in the following ways:

- Id's don't exactly match
- Counts don't match
- In cases where Id's do match, the Name's don't exactly match (case-sensitive)

I have tried the following:

```
if (oldList != newList)
```

And:

```
if (!oldList.SequenceEqual(newList))
```

However, both produce inaccurate results.  I understand I can create a class of type `IEqualityComparer` which implements a `HashSet` comparison; but I also read that it may not work for my case...  Can someone shed any light on how to compare two objects to detect the types of changes I have specified?

Comment: You're going to need to *show us the comparer* if it's not functioning properly.

Comment: _"I also read that it may not work for my case..."_ - I beg to differ. Show that you have implemented and understood comparison. Explain why you think it wouldn't work.

Comment: There are many ways you could compare the two lists... Is order important? Do the objects have a "primary key" (like id)? How should the differences be listed?

Comment: @Servy I haven't implemented the comparer yet because of the doubts that I've mentioned.  Are you saying a comparer is the way to go here (despite what I've read to the contrary)?

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, `if (oldList != newList)` isn't going to work, even with a custom comparer...

Comment: @Servy It can be used to exclude self-checking (x == x). I do prefer `if (!object.ReferenceEquals(oldList, newList))`

Comment: @user1477388 `SequenceEqual` can tell you if the sequences are equal, assuming you implement equality as you desire, and you want order to matter.

Comment: But `SequenceEqual` clearly won't tell you the difference! It is very "binary"... Equal or not equal.

Comment: @xanatos The point is that it isn't going to have the desired semantics, and there's no way to change that just using the `==` operator.  As to your last comment: "I would like to write something to compare the two lists and **return boolean true if the lists are different**."

Comment: _"I haven't implemented the comparer yet because of the doubts that I've mentioned"_ - is _"I also read that it may not work for my case"_ your "doubt"? Explain specifically what you read and why you think that won't work.

Comment: @Servy I had ordered the list by the same key and attempted to use the default SequenceEqual(), not implementing my own type.  I guess after what I read, I wasn't sure how to write the IEqualityComparer to meet my needs.  Can you provide an example of what it should look like.  All the ones I saw performed a `HashSet` comparison which seemed to compare the "reference type" meaning that it was the exact same reference in memory (I think).  I just want to compare the properties and the orders of those properties to see if there are any discrepancies.

Comment: @user1477388 All you need to do is write a method that determines when two objects are actually equal, given whatever definition of equality you want to use.  That's it.  If you've written an implementation and are having problems, you can show us what it is.  If you haven't even tried, you have no problem for us to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said, you only need to implement the correct `IEquatable<MyObject>` interface in your `MyObject`, or implement an `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>`

```
/// <summary>
/// Fully equatable MyObject
/// </summary>
public class MyObject : IEquatable<MyObject>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // obj is object, so we can use its == operator
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        MyObject other = obj as MyObject;

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.InnerEquals(other);
    }

    public bool Equals(MyObject other)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.InnerEquals(other);
    }

    private bool InnerEquals(MyObject other)
    {
        // Here we know that other != null;

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return this.Id == other.Id && this.Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            // From http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/613130
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + this.Id.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (this.Name != null ? this.Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can use

```
if (!oldList.SequenceEqual(newList))
```

Note that this **will** compare element order! If you change element order, then the comparison will return `false`

Or you can use an "external" `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>`

```
public class MyObjectEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public static readonly MyObjectEqualityComparer Default = new MyObjectEqualityComparer();

    protected MyObjectEqualityComparer()
    {
    }

    public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null))
        {
            return object.ReferenceEquals(y, null);
        }

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Here we know that x != null && y != null;

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        unchecked
        {
            // From http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/613130
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.Id.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.Name != null ? obj.Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

use it like

```
if (!oldList.SequenceEqual(newList, MyObjectEqualityComparer.Default))
```

Note that there are various schools of thought on how exactly to write equality comparers, and there is a little caveat: if you override the `operator==` you must be very very wary of not using it inside your comparator :-)

A classical example of wrong code, when the `operator==` is overloaded

```
public bool Equals(MyObject other)
{
    // BOOOM!!! StackOverflowException!
    // Equals will call operator== that will probably call
    // Equals back! and so on and so on.
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return this.InnerEquals(other);
}
```

So it is better to do `object.ReferenceEquals(something, someotherthing)` that does reference comparison.

Then there is the problem of `null` handling with properties:

The hash of `Name` (a `string`) is written like this:

```
hash = hash * 23 + obj.Name != null ? obj.Name.GetHashCode() : 0
```

so that if `obj.Name` is `null` the code doesn't expode in a `NullReferenceException`. Automatically generated code for anonymous objects use another way:

```
hash = hash * 23 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(obj.Name);
```

The `EqualityComparer<string>.Default` is safe to use, even with `null` values.

For the `Equals` comparison of properties, the automatically generated code for anonymous objects uses another funny trick:

```
&& EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(this.Name, obj.Name);
```

so it uses `EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals`, that then correctly uses the various methods/interfaces to compare objects.

Comment: I've seen that argument before about `==` but how would that overloaded `==` operator look to cause that problem yet still cope with `null`s itself?

Comment: See the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx It's interesting because it overloads `==` yet **doesn't** use `Object.ReferenceEquals`

Comment: @weston Use the `object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)`. With `struct` types it is useless, because you can't clearly have two "same" value types (they will always be different instances)

Comment: Or you can downcast to `object` :-) (as done in the link) `((object)person1 == null || ((object)person2) == null)` In C# the operators aren't `virtual`, so if you downcast you use the operator of the downcasted class.

Comment: The point is, the work must be done in the `==` be that the downcast, or `ReferenceEquals`. If you don't null check the parameters to `==`, you risk calling `null.equals(..)`

Comment: @weston Yes, but A) You downcast to object and use == or B) you use object.ReferenceEquals(x, null). You don't do `x == null` (because you then become recursive and stack overflow)

Comment: See example in link: `Person personObj = obj as Person; if (personObj == null)` It does do this. And doesn't cause circular because `==` itself performs a `null` check which it must do.

Comment: So that's `==` in both the `Equals` methods, on variables of type `Person`

Comment: I think you could only get a stackoverflow with an incorrect `==` implementation. i.e. one that does not do `null` checks itself.

Comment: @weston The example given is playing with fire... It is going from `Equal` to `==` to `Equal`. That example is correct, but I'm not even able to comprehend how it works exactly. It is **very** error prone.

Comment: Well it's not the same `Equals` method. It goes from `Person.Equals` to `==` to `Object.Equals` in the case of a `null`/non `Person` object. As for playing with fire, it's easy to make a mistake in either approach. I'd hope that all cases are covered by tests in production and would catch SO and other errors.